# Depth To Water Index - How to Extend the Wetland Boundary Based on Parameters

Tags: qgis, nearest-neighbor

I recently reached out to ask about how to develop a Cartographic Depth-to-Water index (DTW) following the methods described in the paper below:

*Using the Cartographic Depth-to-Water Index to Locate Small Streams and Associated Wet Areas across Landscapes
Barry White,Jae Ogilvie,David M.H. M.H. Campbell,Douglas Hiltz,Brian Gauthier,H. Kyle H. Chisholm, show all
Pages 333-347 | Published online: 23 Jan 2013
Download citation https://doi.org/10.4296/cwrj2011-909*

Since then, I figured out how to develop a DTW index but I am noticing bog features are not being detected very well using this model. There is a mention of how the boundaries were corrected using the following description:

*For the purpose of DEM-based wetland delineation, it was necessary to extend the wetland borders beyond the DTW <1 m areas. This was done by including all flat areas beyond DTW > 1 m as long as the mean standard deviation of the DEM within the 30 m neighbourhood of each grid cell remained < 0.1 m. Within these areas, canopy heights would generally be < 4 m.*

I am new to modeling so I am not sure how to do this. I have ideas but not sure how to execute. This is what I was thinking:

1. Define flat areas. Create a slope raster and make a boolian raster of areas with <=2%.
2. Do a nearest neighbour analysis?

The thing is, I am not too sure how to do this at all.

Comment: I think the latter part of the task (creating a SD map) is achievable by **Focal Statistics** tool in the Processing Toolbox > SAGA > Spatial and Geostatistics-Rasters > Focal Statistics.

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks and other statements of appreciation within your posts.